# Downloading Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I was downloading Ubuntu 16.04 but it has downloaded a 4.86MB iso file whereas the 1.4 GB ubuntu download is still going on. Can anyone tell me why 2 files are being downloaded?

Comment: Are you using WiFi or ethernet.And when you ping is there packet loss

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

There is no 4.86 MB Ubuntu ISO file; the absolute smallest one is 54MB. 
It's possible that your browser is storing the partial download in a temporary file; you can check to see if that file's size changes as your download progresses. If it is increasing in size, then your download is probably fine, and your browser will automatically merge the two files when the download is complete.

If you're having persistent download issues, you could try using a different browser, a download manager, or use the torrent download option for the Ubuntu ISO: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Your edit on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/792896/451919) got rejected because it conflicted with another edit I was doing at the same time. Could you do the edit again?

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Firefox, for example, will create a file with the same name as the file being downloaded with the extra suffix ".part", and this file will store all the data that has been downloaded so far. It will grow in size and eventually reach the final size of the file, whereupon it is renamed to the final file name.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I can think of that could cause this with the information given:

1) The first option is that this is a temporary download file as mentioned above. Even though both those answers suggest you are using Firefox, Google Chrome still must save any downloaded data somewhere on your computer.

2) The other option is that the download failed and automatically restarted itself.

Answer (score -1):

Or try alternativly this link https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Downloads/Xenial_Xerus/

Answer (score -2):

this maybe due to two reasons of which both are not harmful in any way to your download

**1) You must be using firefox because this has happened to me a lot of times (mainly in the case of rar/zip files)**

When I download a file,

Firefox does 2 things: changes the file name to gobbledy-gook of letters and numbers, AND, adds a .part extension -- therefore the files won't open. This is a NEW problem.

If I manually remove the .part extension in the download folder, the file will open, but I still have the problem of the name change. I believe that the .part extension is supposed to go away when the download is finished, Also, my downloads always used to come with their original name, not a numbers/letters name.

2)**Your Antivirus has some serious permissions which you might have given it while installation**

so each and every part of data is reviewed for virus and put in another temporary file until the whole download is complete

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What? The second reason is wrong, a badly installed antivirus will never do that..