# Problem with Virtual Box on Xubuntu running under Android

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, xubuntu, android, chroot

First of all, I'm aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/498900/451919) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/498900/451919), and I don't believe this is a duplicate. I've encountered that problem (and solved it using those answers) on two different laptops. This problem, however, I believe is different. I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that Xubuntu is running under `chroot`.

Also, I realize this may not be solvable at all. I know that VB depends on some sort of virtualization setting in the BIOS. My device doesn't even *have* a BIOS.

Alright, this is Xubuntu Xenial (x86-64) running under `chroot` on an Android device. ([Details here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/149591/131868)). It's not a virtual machine. Android and Xubuntu both share the same Linux kernel, and in Android's system monitor, I can see Xubuntu processes as separate tasks. This device has an x86‑64 2.3 Ghz quad core CPU and 4 GB RAM.

By the way, due to the Android thing I'm running an old kernel. `uname -a` gives

```
Linux localhost 3.10.20-x86_64_moor-gc55829a #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 4 01:08:33 CST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Alright, so I run VB by typing `virtualbox` into the Terminal.

The program starts, but I also get this warning:

```
android@localhost:~$ virtualbox
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-gc55829a.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":0.0".
```

In spite of this warning, however, the GUI still appears. However, when I try to run any VM, I get the following message:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine **[name]**.

Clicking a button that says `Details` gives the following message:

> The virtual machine '[name]' has terminated unexpectedly during
>   startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:  MachineWrap
>   Interface:  IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

A separate box says:

> **Kernel driver not installed (rc = -1908)**
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)
>   - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

#### Things I have tried:

- [This answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/499040/451919) All the information given in this question is *after* having done that.
- This:

> android@localhost:~$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
>
> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.10.20-x86_64_moor-gc55829a/modules.dep.bin'
>
> modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/3.10.20-x86_64_moor-gc55829a
>
> android@localhost:~$

Comment: Have you done this: sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup?

Comment: And could you post the output of:  `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms`

Comment: Also, what is the kernel version that both devices share?

Comment: @collDue96 The output of that was `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`

Comment: @collDue96 And as for those other commands, I've ran all of them, and they went flawlessly. No errors.

Comment: @eyoung100 `uname -a` gives 
`Linux localhost 3.10.20-x86_64_moor-gc55829a #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 4 01:08:33 CST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: eyoung100 Wow, by the way, that was a very old kernel.  (Xenial on my laptop has `4.4.0-22`) I suppose it's old because it has to use the same kernel that my Android firmware uses. I guess that could be the reason for the problem?

Comment: Well according to Google 3.10.x-moor-etc-etc is the kernel version for Android Lollipop, aka 5.0.  Is that your version?

Comment: @eyoung100 yup :D And it's the latest I can get without flashing a special ROM :)

Comment: Also, you may have the ARM architecture.  As such the initial error you have may be misleading.  Paste the output of `apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)` into your question.

Comment: @eyoung100 No, I certainly don't have the ARM architecture. This is an x86 device. Should I still post that output? Going to bed now, will see your reply tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41835/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-fiksdal).

Comment: Yes still post the output... I need to verify that the headers for your version exist.  Using the exact match search from `uname -r` will confirm that.

Comment: @eyoung100 That command gave no output. Copied it exactly as you wrote it. Good night. Thanks for your help so far.